# Java Webservice and vectors

Tags: java, web-services

i will like some advice on webservice that im writing, basically was trying to implement a method with code......

```
public static void writeToCustomerFile(Vector<Customer> customer) throws IOException
{
    String strFilePath = "./src/customer.txt";
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFilePath));
    for (int i = 0; i < customer.size(); i++) {
        writer.write("id," + customer.get(i).getName() + "," + customer.get(i).getSurname()+","+customer.get(i).getAccount()+","+customer.get(i).getBalance()+"\n");
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

but it keeps on giving the error message: illegal start of type.

im trying to write this to a file on the serverside using a vector

Bless frederick carter

Answer (score 1):

Did you import class `Vector`?

```
import java.util.Vector;
```

By the way, `Vector` is an old legacy collection class. You should use `List` and `ArrayList` in new code - only use `Vector` when you are dealing with old legacy code which you can't change.

```
import java.util.List;

public static void writeToCustomerFile(List<Customer> customers) throws IOException
{
    // ... code here ...
}
```

To iterate over a list, use a "foreach"-style loop instead of explicitly looking up elements by index:

```
for (Customer cust : customers) {
    writer.write("id," + cust.getName() + "," + cust.getSurname() + "," +
        cust.getAccount() + "," + cust.getBalance() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Jesper, I am in the process of looking into Web Services with Java.  Many of our methods we want return a Vector.  I have put together a client/server test for this and nothing gets returned in the Vector to the client.  Looking at the return SOAP envelope using Nirsoft SocketSniff, the return is empty.  So am I right in thiking Vector cannot be passed over a web service?  90% of our code use Vectors :-( - cheers Andez

Comment: @Andez that depends entirely on what library or framework you are using for your web services. I would not expect `Vector` to give any problems with regard to this; the problem is most likely somewhere else.